# Apportioning $100\%$ across $24$ hours

Tags: random

Assume I have value $x=500$. I would like to apportion this value $500$ across $24$ hours time period and would like it to be apportioned randomly. So if $500$ is $100\%$ the $x\%$ generated at random would be used to apportion the value of $X$ into $24$ segments. Any help?

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum segment size?

Comment: There is no min and maximum. Actually 24 is the number of hours. I have aggregated value for a day which I want to apportion it across 24 hours.

Comment: So one segment can be $0$ or $500$?

Comment: It can be 0 but not 500.

Comment: Well??? So there **IS** a maximum limit!!! What is it? $499$?

Comment: Wow!! You'r right.  I'm sorry now I get it,it cannot go beyond 10% value of X.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26911/discussion-between-siva-karthikeyan-and-barak-manos).

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of $23$ random numbers between $0$ and $500$ inclusive.  Append $0$ and $500$ to the list, and sort it.  Each hour's allotment is the difference between two adjacent numbers in the sorted list.  (This rule allows both $0$ and $500$; excluding $500$ is a bit trickier.)

Comment: I'm not convinced that putting numbers in TeX makes them significantly more legible.